# Can't boot into Windows installed on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, boot-repair

I have 1TB HDD and 500 GB m.2 nvme SSD on my laptop , I had installed windows on the sad and then I tried to dual boot with Ubuntu and installed Ubuntu in my HDD but now when i turn on my laptop i can't see my windows option just "1. Ubuntu 2. Advance Ubuntu options"(these two options show up) and no Windows 10 option and i can't see my SSD in my bios, even in bios under boot order it says "hard drive : Ubuntu" and CD/DVD and USB drive .

When I boot into Ubuntu I can see my SSD in "Other locations" with all my windows files and folder in it

Can anyone help me how do I boot into windows?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Are both systems installed in UEFI boot mode?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  Is Windows fast start up off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)